# Problem with datetime.time() comparison in a pre_save signal

Tags: django, python-3.x, datetime, django-models, django-timezone

I have those models:

```
class Interval(models.Model):
    from_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False)
    to_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False)

class CheckIn(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    interval = models.ForeignKey(Interval, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

**The main goal is:**

When a `CheckIn` is created the code should check if it's within the given interval's time. I need to compare those two and return their difference in `%H:%M:%S` format.

**What I've done so far:**

Since i have different scenarios what to do with the given `CheckIn` before it gets saved, I am using a `pre_save` signal and the time comparison is a part of these scenarios. Here is a pseudo:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=CheckIn)
def set_action_state(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if something:
       ...
       if another:
          ...
       else:
          ...
    else:
        # instance.date_time.time() is 13:56:56.568860 (2 hours behind, it should be 15 instead of 13)
        # instance.interval.from_time is 15:07:40
        if instance.date_time.time() < instance.interval.from_time:
            # this returns True when it's meant to return False
```

`instance.date_time` is a timezone aware date, since i  can print it's `tzinfo` which returns `UTC` instead of  `Europe/Sofia` as of my `TIME_ZONE` in settings and I have no clue why.

So I manually tried to set it's `tz` by doing:

```
tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Sofia')
dt1 = instance.date_time.replace(tzinfo=tz)
print(dt1.tzinfo) # which is the correct Europe/Sofia
print(dt1) # which is 13:56:56.568860, again 2 hours behind even with different timezone.
```

The second thing i tried is to convert `instance.interval.from_time` to aware datetime and then compare both dates' `time()`.

```
def time_to_datetime(date, time):
    return make_aware(datetime.datetime.combine(date, time))

dt2 = time_to_datetime(dt1.date(), instance.interval.from_time)
print(dt2.tzinfo) #this returns 'Europe/Sofia'
print(dt2) #this is 15:07:40
```

Now both `dt1` and `dt2` are aware but still no luck comparing them. Here's the complete code:

```
tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Sofia')
dt1 = instance.date_time.replace(tzinfo=tz)
dt2 = time_to_datetime(dt1.date(), instance.interval.from_time)
print(dt1.time() < dt2.time()) # this is True
print(dt1.tzinfo) # 'Europe/Sofia'
print(dt2.tzinfo) # 'Europe/Sofia'
print(dt1.time()) # 13:56:56.568860
print(dt1.time()) # 15:07:40
```

**How can I get the proper time in `dt1` and this comparison to work properly, even when both datetimes are aware with a proper timezone?**

**EDIT:** I have `USE_TZ = True` in my settings.

Comment: can you try again create new intervals and checkin then compare in  pre_save after changing `instance.date_time.replace(tzinfo=tz)`?

Comment: Same result, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you add USE_TZ = True , in your settings.py ?

Comment: Yeah, i'll update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django doesn't make any guarantees about what the timezone of your datetimes will be in Python code. That's because 1) timezones are mostly relevant for user interaction (which is why `activate()` affects forms and templates) and 2) Python comparison operations are timezone-aware, so the specific timezone doesn't affect the outcome.

Of course, one operation that is not timezone-aware is extracting the time from a datetime and comparing it to another time. Therefore you have to manually convert your datetime to the right timezone. You had the right idea, but `replace()` is the wrong way to do it. (Rather than merely *converting* to another timezone, it *changes* the actual moment in time.)

Instead, do this:

```
from django.utils.timezone import localtime

if localtime(instance.date_time).time() < instance.interval.from_time:
    pass
```

Comment: That was exactly what i needed. I knew there was a difference between user's `datetime` and python's `datetime` but I thought converting them to equal timezone would convert their date and time in python as well. Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

I did some googling and found that django intend to always save in `UTC` format in model but during retrive from db in converted into TIME_ZONE set by settings. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184370/django-should-i-convert-an-aware-datetime-instance-to-utc-before-posting-to-a-m). So i suppose there is a possibility its in `UTC` format in pre-save instance. I might be wrong as i don't have concrete strong knowledge about it.

I think this comparison needs to done in real time. So its quite safe to use user TIME_ZONE now to compare with interval from_time. So my suggestion

```
import pytz
import datetime


tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Sofia')
curtime = tz.localize(datetime.datetime.now())
```

and convert this line of code

```
  if instance.date_time.time() < instance.interval.from_time:
            # this returns True when it's meant to return False
```

to

```
   if curtime < instance.interval.from_time:
            # I hope this return False now
```

Comment: Unfortunately this throws `ValueError: Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)`

Comment: I am really sorry for that. As you already set your timeZone can you please try with timezone.now() [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects)

Comment: My datetime.datetime object is already timezone aware, so there is no need to replace it with timezone.now(), it would produce the same error.